# Find the poles of this function

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

$$F(z) = \frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)\coth(\pi z)}{z^3}$$

The book says this function has a pole of order 5 at $z=0$

Then the book says this has poles at (**simple poles**):

$z = \pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3, ....$

$z = \pm i, \pm 2i, \pm 3i, ...$

I dont get how those are the simple poles, the function isnt undefined at those points.

How should I do this?

Comment: All poles are points where the function is undefined.

Comment: $\cot(\pi z) = \frac{1}{tan\pi z}$, $\coth{\pi z} = \frac{1}{\tanh\pi z}$, substitute the values of $z$ into both and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Other than at $z=0$, the denominator $z^3$ does nothing interesting in terms of causing or cancelling potential poles.  So the non-zero poles of $F(z)$ will be contained in the union of the poles of $\cot (\pi z)$ and the poles of $\cot (\pi z)$.  (One could imagine a pole of one being wiped out by coinciding with at least as strong a zero of the other; for this $F(z)$ that does not happen so the set poles is in fact the union.)

Let's look at the be poles of 
$$\cot (\pi z) = i\frac{e^{i\pi z} + e^{i\pi z}}{e^{i\pi z} + e^{i\pi z}}$$
Let 
$$
z = n + \delta + i \phi$$
with $n\in \Bbb{Z}-\{0\}$ and $\delta, \phi \in \Bbb{R}$ with $| \delta| \leq \frac{1}{2}$. 
A modest amount of algebra, using the fact that $e^{i\pi n} = \pm 1$, yields
$$\cot (\pi z) =i\frac{e^{-\pi\phi}(\cos \delta + i\sin \delta)+e^{+\pi\phi}(\cos \delta - i\sin \delta)}{e^{-\pi\phi}(\cos \delta - i\sin \delta)+e^{+\pi\phi}(\cos \delta - i\sin \delta)}$$
For this to be a pole the denominator must approach zero.  The real part of the denominator can  approach zero only if $\phi \approx 0$ or $\cos \delta \approx 0$. If $\cos \delta \approx 0$ then $|\sin \delta \approx 1$ so the imaginary part of the denominator will approach zero only if $\phi \approx 0$; thus all the poles of $\cot (\pi z)$ lie on the real axis, and are at $z = \pm n$.  These are poles of order 1, stemming from the $\pm x$ behaviors of $\sin(n\pi + x)$ for small $x$.

Similarly, all the poles of $\coth(\pi z)$ lie at $z = \pm i n$.